# Does anyone know how I can convert DNA code into FASTA for this TTGAAACACTGGATGAATGAAAAGCCCTGCTTTGCAACCCCTCAGC

Tags: sequence-alignment, fasta, sequence-analysis, phylogenetics

TTGAAACACTGGATGAATGAAAAGCCCTGCTTTGCAACCCCTCAGC this is the DNA code Sequence. I have tried converting each into the amino acid and ended up with this LKHWMNEKPCFATPQX but I was told that this isn't right.

Comment: So you googled what fasta format looks like for DNA, and you concluded from what you read that it meant to translate the DNA into protein?

Comment: FASTA is a sequence format, and it is used for any sequence, including DNA and protein sequence. Translating DNA to protein sequence does not require FASTA or any format, for that matter - the sequence itself is enough. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is your nuc seq as a fasta:

```
>sequence_1
TTGAAACACTGGATGAATGAAAAGCCCTGCTTTGCAACCCCTCAGC
```

To translate it use an online tool (ie https://web.expasy.org/translate/) or do it in biopython:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for record in SeqIO.parse("/path/seq1.fa", "fasta"):
    print ('nuc', record, sep='\n')
    print ('prot', record.translate(), sep='\n')
```

Which gives:

```
nuc
ID: sequence_1
Name: sequence_1
Description: sequence_1
Number of features: 0
Seq('TTGAAACACTGGATGAATGAAAAGCCCTGCTTTGCAACCCCTCAGC', SingleLetterAlphabet())
prot
ID: <unknown id>
Name: <unknown name>
Description: <unknown description>
Number of features: 0
Seq('LKHWMNEKPCFATPQ', ExtendedIUPACProtein())
```

Note, this defaults to the human codon table. Other codon tables are available with the parameter 'table'.